# Wildly varying hashing performance with CFSet and CFDictionary on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, performance, hash, core-foundation

When using `CFSet` and `CFDictionary` configured with custom callbacks to use integers as their keys, I've noticed some wildly varying performance of their internal hashing implementation. I'm using 64 bit integers (int64_t) with a range of roughly 1 - 1,000,000.

While profiling my application with, I noticed that every so often, a certain combination of factors would produce unusually poor performance. Looking at Instruments, `CFBasicHash` was taking much longer than usual.

After a bunch of investigating, I finally narrowed things down to a set of 400,000 integers that, when added to a `CFSet` or `CFDictionary` cause terrible performance with hashing.

The hashing implementation in [CFBasicHash.m](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.42/CFBasicHash.m) is beyond my understating for a problem like this, so I was wondering if anyone had any idea why such a completely random set of integers could cause such dreadful performance.

The following test application will output an average iteration time of `37ms` for adding sequential integers to a set, but an average run time of `3622ms` when adding *the same number* of integers but from the problematic data set.

*(And if you insert the same number of completely random integers, then performance is much closer to `37ms`. As well, adding these problematic integers to an `std::map` or `std:set` produces acceptable performance.)*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern uint64_t dispatch_benchmark(size_t count, void (^block)(void));

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSString *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"Integers.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSArray *components = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSInteger count = components.count;

    int64_t *numbers = (int64_t *)malloc(sizeof(int64_t) * count);
    int64_t *sequentialNumbers = (int64_t *)malloc(sizeof(int64_t) * count);

    for (NSInteger c = 0; c < count; c++) {
      numbers[c] = [components[c] integerValue];
      sequentialNumbers[c] = c;
    }

    NSLog(@"Beginning test with %@ numbers...", @(count));

    // Test #1 - Loading sequential integers

    uint64_t t1 = dispatch_benchmark(10, ^{
      CFMutableSetRef mutableSetRef = CFSetCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL);

      for (NSInteger c = 0; c < count; c++) {
        CFSetAddValue(mutableSetRef, (const void *)sequentialNumbers[c]);
      }

      NSLog(@"Sequential iteration completed with %@ items in set.", @(CFSetGetCount(mutableSetRef)));

      CFRelease(mutableSetRef);
    });

    NSLog(@"Sequential Numbers Average Runtime: %llu ms", t1 / NSEC_PER_MSEC);
    NSLog(@"-----");

    // Test #2 - Loading data set

    uint64_t t2 = dispatch_benchmark(10, ^{
      CFMutableSetRef mutableSetRef = CFSetCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL);

      for (NSInteger c = 0; c < count; c++) {
        CFSetAddValue(mutableSetRef, (const void *)numbers[c]);
      }

      NSLog(@"Dataset iteration completed with %@ items in set.", @(CFSetGetCount(mutableSetRef)));

      CFRelease(mutableSetRef);
    });

    NSLog(@"Dataset Average Runtime: %llu ms", t2 / NSEC_PER_MSEC);

    free(sequentialNumbers);
    free(numbers);
  }
}
```

Example output:

- Sequential Numbers Average Runtime: 37 ms
- Dataset Average Runtime: 3622 ms

The integers are available here:

- [Gist (Integers.txt)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/867493fe8dbf5c059c37) or [Dropbox (Integers.txt)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw418nagjleukio/Integers.txt?dl=0)

Can anyone help explain what is "special" about the given integers that might cause such a degradation in the hashing implementation used by `CFSet` and `CFDictionary`?